# How many edges ensure that a graph always contains a complete subgraph $K_n$?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

The complete graph $K_n$ is the graph with $n$ vertices where any two vertices are connected by an edge.

The complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ is the graph with $2n$ vertices which can be partitioned into two subsets $V_1$ and $V_2$ of size $n$ such that any two vertices $a\in V_i$, $b\in V_j$, are connected by an edge if and only if $i\neq j$.

Let $m\geq 1$ be arbitrarily large.

1. What is the minimum value $f(m)$ such that any graph with $m$ vertices and at least $f(m)$ edges contains $K_n$ as a subgraph?
2. What is the minimum value $g(m)$ such that any graph with $m$ vertices and at least $g(m)$ edges contains $K_{n,n}$ as a subgraph?

I am particularly interested in the order ($O(f)$, $O(g)$, $o(f)$, $o(g)$) of the functions $f$ and $g$, and whether it is quadratic or linear.

Some observations:

${{n}\choose{2}} \leq f(m) \leq {{m}\choose{2}}$.

$n^2 \leq g(m) \leq {{m}\choose{2}}$.

$g(n)\leq f(2n)$.

$f(m) \leq {{m}\choose{2}} - (m-n+1) + 1 = \frac{m^2}{2} - \frac{3m}{2} +n$.

To see that the last observation holds let's pick a graph $G=(V,E)$ of size $m$ with no $K_n$ subgraph. We show that $|E|\leq {{m}\choose{2}} - (m-n+1)$.

Pick a subset $V_1$ of $n$ vertices and then fix an edge $e_1$ between vertices in $V_1$ that is not in $E$ (by assumption it always exists). Then create $V_2 \subseteq V$ by taking away one of the two vertices connected by $e_1$, which we denote $a_1$, and adding a new vertex from $V \setminus V_1$. We repeat the process to find a missing edge $e_2$ in the subgraph induced by $V_2$ and create $V_3$ by erasing a vertex $a_2$ connected by $e_2$ and adding a new vertex in $V\setminus (V_2 \cup \{a_1\})$. We repeat the process and end up with $m-n+1$ missing vertices in $G$, namely $e_1, e_2, \ldots$.

Comment: are you sure about your $\binom{m}{2}$ bound? The usual Ramsey Theory bound only gives something like $\binom{2m-2}{m-1}$

Comment: @dezdichado isn't ${m}\choose{2}$ simply the maximum number of edges a graph of $m$ vertices can have (i.e. the number of pairs of vertices)? So if it has ${m}\choose{2}$ edges then it is complete.

Comment: oh I think I am misreading your question then.

Comment: For $K_n$, check [Turán's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem). The explicit limit is given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213226/deriving-the-number-of-edges-in-a-tur%c3%a1n-graph).

Comment: For $K_{n,n}$, if the graph is restricted to a bipartite graph, the problem is called [the Zarankiewicz problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zarankiewicz_problem)

Comment: @Apass.Jack thanks that is what I was looking for.